# How to check if a string contains a special character (!@#$%^&*()_+)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I was wondering what would be the best way to check if a string as

```
$str
```

contains any of the following characters

```
!@#$%^&*()_+
```

I thought of using ASCII values but was a little confused on exactly how that would be implemented.

Or if there is a simpler way to just check the string against the values.

Comment: If you just want to check for non-alphanumerics, by the way, that would be `[[ $str = *[^[:alnum:]]* ]]`.

Comment: ...or, to check for any/all kinds of punctuation, `[[ $str = *[[:punct:]]* ]]`. In general, using POSIX character classes (any character class in `man 7 regexp` on Linux will work, even though glob-style patterns aren't POSIX REs) rather than listing out characters one-by-one is a good idea, if there's a character class that fits (or whose negation fits) what you're doing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Match it against a glob. You just have to escape the characters that the shell otherwise considers special:

```
#!/bin/bash
str='some text with @ in it'
if [[ $str == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]]
then
  echo "It contains one of those"
fi
```

Answer (score 10):

This is portable to Dash et al. and IMHO more elegant.

```
case $str in
  *['!&()'@#$%^*_+]* ) echo yup ;;
esac
```

Comment: I'm getting this error:
`````
syntax error near unexpected token `&'
`  *['!'@#$%^&*()_+]* ) echo yup ;;'
`````

Comment: @t7e Thanks for the feedback; looks like `()&` need to be single-quoted too. Updated the answer. I had tested this in various shells but I was able to repro your problem with `/bin/dash` on MacOS Monterey.

Comment: thanks, now it works. Could you let me know how to exclude square and curly brackets in this script as well `[]`  `{}`?

Comment: `*['!&(){}[]'@#$%^*_+]* ) echo yup ;;` seems that this works. But vim colors it as if it is a wrong square bracket escaping. Works in zsh, dash and bash on Ubuntu though. Not sure about its portability.

Comment: You might want to backslash-escape instead of single-quote some characters instead in the hopes that it will appease `vim`. Obviously add any additional characters you like inside the square brackets.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a regexp:

```
if [[ $str =~ ['!@#$%^&*()_+'] ]]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

Some notes:

- The regexp includes the square brackets
- The regexp must not be quoted (so `$str =~ '[!...+]'` would not work).
- There is no need to escape chars as is necessary with the glob approach in another answer, because the chars are between the brackets, where they are taken literally by regexp
- as with glob pattern `[]` means "anything in the contained string"
- because the pattern does not start with `^` or end with `$` there will be a match anywhere in the `$str`.

Comment: It could not catch a `[` or `]`, I tried including them in the list as:  `'!@#$%^&*()_+[]'` didn't work, `'!@#$%^&*()_+\[\]'` didn't work either. How can `[,]` be included?

Comment: Just checked, if we put only one of them at a time in that list, it works. Putting them together (meaning in one go, not necessarily together in space only) doesn't work.

Comment: @quanta try `if [[ $str =~ ['!@#$%^&*()\[\]_+'] ]]; then`

Comment: `str="some string ]"; [[ $str =~ ['!@#$%^&*()\[\]_+'] ]] && echo "Yes"` returns nothing. Ofcourse using an `or` will work: `$str =~ ['[!@#$%^&*()_+'] || $str =~ [']!@#$%^&*()_+']` but this is not a beautiful solution! What is so special about `[` and `]` together?? Even if they are separated!

Comment: The right bracket is the problem, the left one is not special and can be anywhere the in the bracket expression, whereas the right one is recognized only if it is first: `[[ $str =~ [']!@#$%^&*[()_+'] ]]`. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05: "The right-bracket ( ']' ) shall lose its special meaning and represent itself in a bracket expression if it occurs first in the list"

Comment: @Oliver , how can we add check for single and double quotes  ( ' and ") along with this set?

Answer (score 1):

Using expr

```
str='some text with @ in it'
if [ `expr "$str" : ".*[!@#\$%^\&*()_+].*"` -gt 0 ];
    then 
       echo "This str contain sspecial symbol"; 
       fi
```

Comment: There was a time when `expr` was unavoidable but this wasn't one of those cases even back then in the dark ages.

Answer (score 0):

I think one simple way of doing would be like remove any alphanumeric characters and space.

`echo "$str" | grep -v "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"`

If you have a bunch of strings then put them in a file like strFile and following command would do the needful.

`cat strFile | grep -v "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$"`

Comment: You want to lose the [useless `cat`](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat).