# How to match substring with special characters in linux shell?

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to check if a file contains a string in bash. I have done so for regular string characters. However, i need to check a new string which contains double quote ".

Say the string is:

```
PARAMETER_XYZ="no"
```

I tried this, but does not work:

```
ABC=$(cat /etc/file)
if [[ $ABC = *"PARAMETER_XYZ=\"no\""*]] ; then
   exit 0
fi
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `grep -Fq 'PARAMETER_XYZ="no"' /etc/file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check a string if it contains a special character (!@#$%^&\*()\_+)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26621736/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is the program of choice to look for the presence of strings.

```
if grep 'PARAMETER_XYZ="no"' /etc/file > /dev/null then
   exit 0
fi
```

You can also still do it with `[[` if you really want:

```
ABC=$(cat /etc/file)
if [[ $ABC = *'PARAMETER_XYZ="no"'* ]] ; then
   exit 0
fi
```

However, if that's actually a config file you're trying to parse, there are better solutions that are less fragile than looking for an exact string. That file looks like it might even be a shell variables file, in which case you could just `source` it and then check $PARAMETER_XYZ directly.

Comment: It is a config file. What would be a better solution?

Comment: Depends on the format. If all of the lines look like that, and you trust it, you could `source` it and then just see if $PARAMETER_XYZ equals "no".

Comment: Yes, all the lines looks like this except some others lines starts with # as comments. Could you add this method to your answer? I will take this. Thank you!

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Just one more question, if I source it, these parameters stays in my shell environment. Would that have undesirable effects?

Comment: It depends exactly what they're called, but you could do the source and checking in a subshell to avoid the problem, since subshells lose their variables when they end.

Comment: Actually, if I source, then none of the shell script after source get executed. Could you show me how to check the variables after sourcing them in a subshell? I asked the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673779/how-to-check-environment-variable-in-a-linux-subshell

Comment: i am still debugging. it may be due to other reasons.