# How to check environment variable in a linux subshell?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a config file which I can $source and check the variable values in it. However, I do not want to contaminate my current shell environment while still want to check the value of the variables.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start a second shell.

```
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# cat envars
export BOOGER='yuck'
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# env | grep BOOGER
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# bash
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# source envars
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# env | grep BOOGER
BOOGER=yuck
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# exit
exit
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]# env | grep BOOGER
[root@feaf38f55954 ~]#
```

Comment: You can also inline that with `(. envars && env | grep BOOGER)`, where the subshell is created by `(...)`.

Comment: I could not start a second shell because my program is executing a shell script which needs to check the config file. I am not doing it interactively.

Comment: @drdot If you use command substitution it runs in a subshell, so you can do `var=$(source envvar; env | grep BOOGER)`